# Do something for each cell that is a formula and in column K or row 50?

Tags: excel, vba

I now do something for all formulas in a sheet with the code below. Can I add conditions so that I do the same thing for cells that match

formula AND (is in column K OR is in row 55)?

```
    For Each ran In srcWbk.Sheets("BSC").Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas)
        trgtWbk.Sheets("BSC").Range(ran.Address).Formula = srcWbk.Sheets("BSC").Range(ran.Address).Formula
    Next ran
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
With srcWbk.Sheets("BSC")
    For Each ran In Union(.Rows(55), .Columns("K")).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas)
        trgtWbk.Sheets("BSC").Range(ran.Address).Formula = ran.Formula
    Next ran
End With
```